# Почему не создается сессия?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени друзья есть вот такой код.

```
if($_POST['pass'] AND $_POST['login']){
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT email,id,password FROM users WHERE email ='$login' and password = '$pass';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($myrow['password'] == $pass){
        $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['email'];
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$myrow['id'];
        header("Location: index.php");
```

}}

Может я что то упустил? сессия не создается. Подсобите пожалуйста.

Comment: `session_start()`?

Comment: есть выше, я думаю может foreach нужен после $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result); ???